# Setting listview in alertdialog in Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Am having a listview in alertdialog.And a spearate adapter class for the customlistview. Problem is  Values are in the list but its not displaying in the listview.When I run it in the tablet one empty row is there.Below is my code.I dont think there is error is adapter.Any solution please?

My Adapter:

```
public class Mse_LotAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MSE_Lotno>  implements Filterable{

    List<MSE_Lotno> list;

    List<MSE_Lotno> filterlst;
    // = new ArrayList<MSE_OrderDetails>();
    Context context;

    TextView txtLotnum;
    TextView txtLotqty;

    private ModelFilter filter;

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (filter == null) {
            filter = new ModelFilter();
        }
        return filter;
    }

    public Mse_LotAdapter(Context context, List<MSE_Lotno> value) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super(context, R.layout.twotextview, value);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = value;

        this.filterlst=new ArrayList<MSE_Lotno>(list);
        getFilter();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final int pos = position;

        View view = null;
        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.twotextview, parent, false);

            txtLotnum = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_lotnum);
            txtLotqty = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_lotqty);

            convertView.setTag(new OrdersViewHolder(txtLotnum, txtLotqty));


        } else {
            OrdersViewHolder viewHolder = (OrdersViewHolder) convertView
                    .getTag();
        }

        OrdersViewHolder holder = (OrdersViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        holder.txtLotnum.setText(list.get(position).getLotNo());
        holder.txtLotqty.setText(list.get(position).getLotQty());

        return convertView;

    }

    /** Holds child views for one row. */
    static class OrdersViewHolder {

        TextView txtLotnum;
        TextView txtLotqty;


        public OrdersViewHolder(TextView txtLotnum, TextView txtLotqty) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.txtLotnum = txtLotnum;
            this.txtLotqty = txtLotqty;


        }



        public TextView getTxtitem() {
            return txtLotnum;
        }

        public void setTxtitem(TextView txtLotnum) {
            this.txtLotnum = txtLotnum;
        }

        public TextView getTxtdesc() {
            return txtLotqty;
        }

        public void setTxtdesc(TextView txtdesc) {
            this.txtLotqty = txtdesc;
        }


    }

    private class ModelFilter extends Filter {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
            FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
            if (constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0) {
                ArrayList<MSE_Lotno> filteredItems = new ArrayList<MSE_Lotno>();

                for (int i = 0, l = list.size(); i < l; i++) {
                    MSE_Lotno customer = list.get(i);
                    String strNum = customer.getOrderNo();//tHhCustomer_number();

                    if (strNum.toLowerCase().contains(constraint))//|| strName.toLowerCase().contains(constraint))
                        filteredItems.add(customer);
                }
                result.count = filteredItems.size();
                result.values = filteredItems;
            } else {
                synchronized (this) {
                    result.values = list;//ModelItemsArray;
                    result.count = list.size();
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                      FilterResults results) {

            filterlst = (ArrayList<MSE_Lotno>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            clear();
            for (int i = 0, l = filterlst.size(); i < l; i++)
                add(filterlst.get(i));
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }
    }

}
```

My AlertDialog:

```
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(MseItemList.this);
                    View promptsView = li
                            .inflate(R.layout.mse_shipment_entry, null);

                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            MseItemList.this);
                    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

                    if (qtyOrderd != 0 && qtyOrderd > 0) {
                        btnExit.setVisibility(view.GONE);

                        // create alert dialog
                        final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                        alst = new ArrayList<String>();// initialize array list

                        edt_itemNo = (EditText) promptsView
                                .findViewById(R.id.edt_mseshipItemNo);


                        lstLotnum = (ListView) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.lst_lotnum);

                        dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
                        lotList = dbhelper.getTempItems();
                        dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
                        adapter = new Mse_LotAdapter(MseItemList.this,lotList);
                        lstLotnum.setAdapter(adapter);
         }
alertDialog.show();
    }
```

Layout:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layLotList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layDesc"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/listTitle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="#267ad4"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Lot No"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center|right"
                android:text="Qty"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" >
            </TextView>

        </LinearLayout>

       <ListView
           android:id="@+id/lst_lotnum"
           style="@style/ListViewAppTheme.White"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="200dp">
       </ListView>



    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you post the layout file too?

Comment: @Jude Added.Please check

Comment: Change the outer `LinearLayout`'s orientation to `vertical`. As you have it, the inner `LinearLayout`'s width is pushing the `ListView` out the side. Or, if you did mean for it to be `horizontal`, you'll have to change the `layout_width` on that inner one.

Answer (score 0):

Your LinearLayout's orientation is horizontal. so your listview is besides of first linealayout (which has title).

just change LinearLayout(layLotList)'s orientation to vertical and it will show listview.

atleast it will show listview then you can check its style and listitem's xml file to set its design.